# Обработка текста, замена слов

Tags: c#, .net, текст

Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь осуществить обработку текста, а именно замену слов(макросов). Есть текст примерно такого вида: "Вечером я [RANDOM] по [WORD] топча ногами снег". Таких "макросов" в тексте довольно много и все они разные. Их нужно заменять на определенные значения. Подскажите, есть ли какой-то способ это организовать без вызова огромного количества функций типа `ReplaceRandom(int num), ReplaceWord(string word)` ... ? Для каждого макроса значение статическое.

Answer (score 2):

Функция замены будет вызвана для каждого "макроса", но вы это можете красиво организовать. Сохраните соответсвия строк и их замен в коллекции, а затем организуйте цикл по этой коллекции, заменяя все нужные фрагменты в исходной строке.

Пример:

```
var input = "Вечером я [RANDOM] по [WORD] топча ногами снег";

var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "[RANDOM]", "замена_1" },
        { "[WORD]", "замена_2" }
    };

var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);

foreach (var replacement in replacements)
{
    outputBuilder.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
}

var result = outputBuilder.ToString();
```

**P.S.** При замене фрагментов строки используется `StringBuilder`. Это даст выигрыш при большом количестве замен, потому что на каждую замену не будет создаваться новая строка.

Comment: Спасибо, выгодно. Подумаю ещё над этим вопросом, если ничего не придёт в голову - воспользуюсь вашим способом.

Comment: А если что-нибудь придет - делитесь :)

Comment: Сейчас подумал о том чтоб спарсить все макросы из текста, запомнить для каждого макроса позицию, заменить их на нужные значения в каком-то Dictonary и потом расставить эти значения по местам. Сейчас иду спать, проснусь и поглубже обдумаю эту идею.